# configuring subdirectory in a wordpress installation for proxy pass to docker application

Tags: nginx, php, reverse-proxy, docker

I have a wordpress installation using Nginx as the web server, now there is a need of adding moodle as the LMS to the same site, as a subdirectory, for example; `www.mysite.com` is where the wordpress site works then moodle would be `www.mysite.com/learn`.

This moodle runs in the same machine in a docker container which uses the [bitnami moodle image](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/moodle); port `8081` is mapped to port `80` of the docker container i.e.

`docker run -d -p 8081:80 -p 4443:443 --name moodle`

I added a location block before wordpress configuration to the nginx config

```
location /learn {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8081;
}
```

the php configuration for wordpress is as follows

```
# Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server (locally with unix: param to avoid network overhead)
location ~ \.php$ {
    # Prevent Zero-day exploit
    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param   APP_ENV  production;
    include         fastcgi_params;
}
```

However this still gives a 404 response when I access `www.amysite.com/learn`

I checked the docker proxy is running bound to all IP addresses

`/usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8081 -container-ip 172.19.0.3 -container-port 80`

also a `wget` to `localhost:8081` gives the moodle installation home page so I'm led to belive it is definitely a problem with my location block; or it is the **Zero Day exploit** config `try_files $uri =404;` causing the issue, even if so, I still can't remove that line.

**Update**

This configuration worked

```
location ~ ^/apply/(.*)$ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8081/$1;
}
```

I can reach Moodle home page but all further URLs break because Moodle is not aware of generating links with the `/learn` context root; think I'll have to reconfigure Moodle to generate `/learn` context URLS